# Changing a label through a button (Java/Swing issue)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jlabel

newbie programmer here:

I just made my first button. I want the button to change the label "Hello World!" to "Hello Universe!". I tried searching for ways to change the label through `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, but failed to find any. If anybody would be kind enough to explain to me how to change the commented section in `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` to change the label, please explain!

Thanks!

My code:

```
package game;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Javagame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    double x=Math.random()*500;
    double y=Math.random()*500;
    protected JButton b1;
    public Javagame() {
        b1 = new JButton("Button!");
        b1.setActionCommand("change");

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        add(b1);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("change".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            //I want a code here that changes "Hello World" to "Hello Universe". Thank you.
        }
    }
    private static void createWindow(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Javagame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        label.setForeground(new Color(0x009900));

        Javagame newContentPane = new Javagame();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have no means of getting a reference to the label to change it....

Move the deceleration of the label to the class level...

```
public class Javagame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    double x=Math.random()*500;
    double y=Math.random()*500;
    protected JButton b1;
    // Add me...
    private JLabel label;
```

Move the label to reside in the panel

```
public Javagame() {
    b1 = new JButton("Button!");
    b1.setActionCommand("change");

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    add(b1);

    // Move me here
    label = new JLabel("Hello World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    label.setForeground(new Color(0x009900));
    add(label);
}
```

Then in your `actionPerformed` method you will be able to reference it...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("change".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        label.setText("I have changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for such a thorough answer! I understood it and tried it, but when I pressed the button (the code ran fine) the console gave me 40 lines of errors complaining that there was an `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"`. Sorry for bothering you but could you walk me through this please? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that I'm missing a library or a javax/swing file elsewhere?

Comment: Full exception? Do you mean this? `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Where's the `NullPointerException` occurring.  The exception should be giving you a class and method name as well as a line number

Comment: Oops. I forgot to enter the second line, sorry: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at game.Javagame.actionPerformed(Javagame.java:25)`

Comment: It sounds like you're shadowing you variables.  Make sure that in the constructor of the `Javagame` class, you're not declaring the label like `JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);` and are instead using what I've shown in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. Seems I got lazy and copy-pasta'd my old code into the new one. By the way, what does "shadowing" a variable mean? Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Basically it means you have higher level reference (in this a class variable) and lower level reference (the method variable) named the same.  Java allows this, but it leads to some very annoying problems that can sometimes be difficult to track...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Javagame extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    double x=Math.random()*500;
    double y=Math.random()*500;
    protected JButton b1;
    // Add me...
    private JLabel label;
public Javagame() {
    b1 = new JButton("Button!");
    b1.setActionCommand("change");

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    add(b1);

    // Move me here
    label = new JLabel("Hello World!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
    label.setForeground(new Color(0x009900));
    add(label);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if ("change".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        Javagame.this.label.setText("I have changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, basically you copied the sample code from my answer and generated an example from it?